# How can I turn this string into a datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I have tried various formats but nothing seems to work. The string is:

> 2018-06-04T09:07:30:507Z

I get the error that the string was not in a correct datetime format with everything I try. I first found/ thought the string was in ISO 8601 format but this seems to be wrong as well.

I don't think it should matter but I get this string from an XML input, this is the code I use for that (with the latest variation I tried to make it work):

```
foreach (XmlNode node in parentNode)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in node)
                {
                    switch (child.Name)
                    {
                        case "ShopId":
                            advance.ShopId = child.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "CustomerId":
                            advance.CustomerId = child.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "Reference":
                            advance.Reference = child.InnerText;
                            break;
                        case "Amount":
                            advance.Amount = decimal.Parse(child.InnerText.Replace('.', ','));
                            break;
                        case "DateStart":
                            advance.DateStart = DateTime.Parse(child.InnerText, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
                            break;
                        case "DateEnd":
                            advance.DateEnd = DateTime.Parse(child.InnerText);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: FYI the problem is that the delimiter between seconds and milliseconds is a colon instead of a period.

Comment: This is UTC format, easier would be to convert one to string and print, you will see the formatting issue, as one mentioned by @juharr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the format manually:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I thought there was a standard pattern but <strike>I can't locate one that accepts the "T" in the middle here</strike> as juharr points out, the incoming data is not in a standard format. So a custom format it has to be.

Comment: I think the T should not cause an issue as it specifies it is a long time. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#LongTime

Comment: The `T` is not the problem, it's the use of a colon instead of a period between the seconds and milliseconds.  If you change it to a period then `DateTime.Parse` will work.

Comment: @juharr - right but what if that `:` is indeed in the input data? I wouldn't favour some string based cleanup over a custom format. It comes from xml.InnerText.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that.  I'm referring to your comment about finding a standard pattern.  You will not find one that uses a colon there instead of a period, the T has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -5):

Since you have a String I wold try the easiest way:

The lenght of particular sections, like year (2018 => 4 chars) does not change,

so you can just cut entire date into pasrts using couple of Substring methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

I know it seems a bit stupid, but as long as it work...